# When is it NOT okay to use onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()

Tags: android, orientation

Documentation of `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` says **"This function is called purely as an optimization, and you must not rely on it being called."**

Under what circumstances will `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` not be called?

Some background on what I am trying to achieve: I want to my `activity` to be notified of `orientation` change reliably *(but also want activity to be killed & restarted as usual)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want the activity to restart (calling onCreate->onResume) again on orientation change you don't place configChanges="orientation" in the manifest. you can check the orientation of the screen in the onCreate method of your activity which is probably what you need. if you dont want the activity to restart itself but rather just switch orientation then you add the configChanges flag in the manifest for the activity and then only onConfigurationChanged() will be called where you also can get the screen orientation. the second way is good when you have expensive operations running in the onCreate methods (starting threads quering databases etc) and you want to reuse that info/data for portrait and for landscape. even if you want you can change the layout in onConfigurationChanged() the same way its done in on create but you again need to find the references to all the views because their ids are not the same in that case.

In any case if you want to have a reference to something that existed before the orentation change the configChanges way is better for handling the changes but it requires a bit more work if you are changing layouts or something.

Comment: Good points but does not answer my question. What I want is i) Perform a specific action on a "complex" object I have in activity when orientation change happens ii) After performing the operation, let activity be killed & recreated as usual. I can't find a reliable way of doing this.

Comment: For my requirements, which I outlined in previous comment, I was thinking of using onRetainNonConfigurationInstance(). But saw the documentation indication that it is not "reliable", hence my question.

Comment: Well the reliability comes with the fact that the activity might restart for reasons different than orientation change. so the only important thing there is to actually have a null check when you call getLastNonConfigurationInstance() and if null then fetch that data again or have some sort of mechanism to recover from something like that. but in general this you need to test. if this gives you issues along the way then redo it with config changes.